# Missing XML tag This required tag is missing. Please add it and resubmit

Tags: xml, sitemap

I'm having trouble with the following [sitemap](http://codingforspeed.com/forum/sitemap.php):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sitemapindex xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
  <sitemap>
    <loc>http://codingforspeed.com/forum/sitemap.php?fid=1</loc>
    <lastmod>2015-07-06 12:42:18</lastmod>
  </sitemap>
  <sitemap>
    <loc>http://codingforspeed.com/forum/sitemap.php?fid=3</loc>
    <lastmod>2015-07-06 12:42:18</lastmod>
  </sitemap>
  <sitemap>
    <loc>http://codingforspeed.com/forum/sitemap.php?fid=4</loc>
    <lastmod>2015-07-06 12:42:18</lastmod>
  </sitemap>
  <sitemap>
    <loc>http://codingforspeed.com/forum/sitemap.php?fid=5</loc>
    <lastmod>2015-07-06 12:42:18</lastmod>
  </sitemap>
  <sitemap>
    <loc>http://codingforspeed.com/forum/sitemap.php?fid=6</loc>
    <lastmod>2015-07-06 12:42:18</lastmod>
  </sitemap>
  <sitemap>
    <loc>http://codingforspeed.com/forum/sitemap.php?fid=7</loc>
    <lastmod>2015-07-06 12:42:18</lastmod>
  </sitemap>
</sitemapindex>
```

It is validated perfectly, but when I submit to google web master it complains:

> ```
> Missing XML tag
> This required tag is missing. Please add it and resubmit.
> ```

[image: Google Doesn't Like it]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're serving different sitemap content to Googlebot. This is what we (Google) get when we try to fetch your sitemap:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sitemapindex xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
</sitemapindex>
```

Try to fetch the sitemap itself with Fetch as Google in Search Console (former Webmaster Tools) or with a tool like [Testuri](http://testuri.org/sniffer))

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your sitemap follows the [Sitemaps XML format](http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html) and [validates successfully](http://www.validome.org/google/validate?url=http://codingforspeed.com/forum/sitemap.php&lan%20g=en&googleTyp=INDEX).

Reexamine the error message; you've only posted the first two lines.  ***The remaining lines will provide important clues***:

- **Sitemap**: Make sure that the file you thought you submitted was indeed the file that was validated.
- **Parent tag:** This is important context information regarding the error.
- **Tag:** This is critical; it tells you what tag is missing.
- **Line:** Tells you where in your sitemap file to look for the error.

Comment: have added the screenshot; Parent tag: sitemapindex
Tag: sitemap;  line 3

Comment: @DoctorLai fetch the page using http://testuri.org/sniffer (with the user agent set to Googlebot) or Fetch as Google. You're serving different sitemap content to Googlebot.

Answer (score 0):

The simple way to fix the problem is **not** to submit the sitemap index page to google since the index page is a web page - in text/html format as opposed to text/xml format that is required. You need to submit the individual .xml links on the sitemap.xml page. Although, it could be challenging if you have lots of links since it is a forum.

Answer (score 0):

This error also appears when the sitemap contains zero items. To solve this, you should create content for the sitemap. However, if you know you have made content you should clear/flush your cache from your website, plugins, theme, server et cetera.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.